# Using "strong" for song

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Can we say "strong song" or should we say "powerful song" ? I want to imply that that it's vocal performance is powerful but then I thought "strong" is for describing something physical not a song maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would only use "strong" when comparing it to other songs, or talking about the actor's performance, otherwise I would use ***moving*** or ***powerful*** instead.

> He gave a strong performance.
>
> The song held up strongly on the charts.
>
> That was a powerful song.
>
> That was a moving melody.

Comment: thanks a lot for clarifying.Would you mind I ask if you're a native American?

Comment: I'm native British actually. I just live in America.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with describing a song as *strong*. Although it's less common than *powerful*, the usage [isn't particularly unusual](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strong%20song,powerful%20song&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

I tend to think of a *"strong song"* as one where the song itself has a clear, memorable musical structure, independent of any particular singer's delivery on any particular performance.

A *"powerful song"*, on the other hand, seems more suggestive of a specific performance - or at least, it's as much about the singer's vocal power and delivery as it is about the song.

Comment: Thank you.i enjoyed the diagram approach for validating.I have the same impression as yours..